# Admob Layout for Android

Tags: android-layout, admob

I have the following code....and I can't seem to get the ads to run outside my scroll view. I have tried to follow other questions on this topic. please assist. All of my adds are showing on top of my content. I would prefer the ads run outside my scroll view.

my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />


    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layoutbottom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <!-- android:layout_height="456dp" -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPlaceName"
                style="@style/HeaderText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtURL"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` on your AdView and `android:layout_below="@id/adView"` on your ScrollView.